# Selenium WebDriver with Java: How do I read username and password from an excel file to Java to use in website testing

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java

I am using Selenium WebDriver with Java.

I have an Excel spreadsheet with two columns, one for username and another for password. I need to read those values and use them to create new users.

Comment: Have you searched online? This seems to me the kind of basic task (reading values from a spreadsheet) that would have many examples you could use as a guideline.

Comment: As I see it, this question is not about testing, but (as Kate Paulk mentioned above) about reading Excel file in Java (and then possibly filling two fields with read values), which is **extremely basic homework task** and should not polluting signal in exchange.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading Excel files with Java

Comment: Agree, off-topic. @obulisaravanan - this question on Stack Overflow might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java , or you can just search for "read excel java" for a lot of different results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=read+excel+java

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on the type of excel file. If it is a standard excel file, there is great instructions on reading them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516144/how-to-read-and-write-excel-file-in-java).

If it is a CSV based excel file than treat it as reading a standard text file and do a comma (Or whatever delimiter it uses) as a split. Instructions can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/).

After you have the data, I would personally store them to a hashmap or some other system to track the value pair and then loop through the hashmap (Key being username, value being password) using a .keySet() and then check for those values.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [an example project that uses Java and runs your tests on SauceLabs](http://djangofan.github.io/simple-selenium-builder-framework/).   In this example I drive the tests from a .CSV spreadsheet.  You could easily edit this project to do your required testing and then you can  hook the test up to a Jenkins job to run them on a scheduled basis.